# The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Found ')'

Tags: formula, process-builder

I feel like I'm way off but trying to setup a critiera in process builder that determines if the year 2018 from the picklist Year is selected, and the Call Total field has been modified and the record's LastModifiedDate has been changed, the formula evaluates to true.

I'm receiving these errors when trying to save in process builder's criteria box:

Your changes are saved, but you can't activate this process until you resolve the following errors.
The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Found ')'
The formula expression is invalid: Field AidTrack Call is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

```
ISPICKVAL([AidTrack_Call__c].Year__c,"2018") && 
ISCHANGED(TEXT([AidTrack_Call__c].Call_Total__c=))  && 
Year(DATEVALUE([AidTrack_Call__c].LastModifiedDate)) = Year(Today())
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second line is invalid:

```
ISCHANGED(TEXT([AidTrack_Call__c].Call_Total__c=))  &&
```

It should be:

```
 ISCHANGED([AidTrack_Call__c].Call_Total__c)  &&
```

There should not be any need to convert to text, nor did you need the equals sign (if you had needed it, you would have needed a string on the other side).

Comment: Correct,  Superb Catch